# Deprecate Objective-C interface of a Swift library

Tags: objective-c, swift, deprecation-warning

We are writing our libraries in Swift are marking most of the public API with `@objc`.

But, there are only a few customers left who are using Objective-C and it's causing us a lot of extra effort. Therefore, we are planning on phasing out the use of `@objc`.

Is there a way to deprecate an API for Objective-C only?

Maybe some trick in combination with `@available(..)`?

Answer (score 3):

The other way around would indeed be possible with the use of macros, but marking APIs as available in Swift and deprecated in Objective-C is not possible, as far as I'm aware.

You could use an ugly trick, though:

```swift
@objc
class Foo: NSObject {

    // No `@objc` here!
    func someMethod() { }

    // Visible from Objective-C with the "normal" name and
    // deprecated with a message.
    @objc(someMethod)
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Objective-C API is going away soon")
    func _objcSomeMethod() {
        someMethod()
    }
}
```

Obviously this is not only ugly but also a lot of work, but if you just hide/mark a few key methods that are used often you may get away with it.

If you're doing a commercial library, it may be easier/better to send a newsletter out to your customers alerting them that you're going to remove the Objective-C API (if you know who they are). Give them a time-frame, e.g. *"We're going to remove Objective-C support on (exact date 6 months from now)."*